# Youtube OEmbed width can't be greater than 740px?

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, embed, oembed

I'm trying to use [Youtube's oEmbed functionality](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html) to get a video embed at 960x580, but for some reason it seems to be maxing out at 740. Please see below:

#### Request:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DbDOYN-6gdRE&format=json&maxwidth=960&maxheight=580
```

#### Response:

```
{
    "provider_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/",
    "title": "1 of 4 Dr. Bill Lands on Cardiovascular Disease: Omega-6 displaces Omega-3",
    "html": "\u003cobject width=\"740\" height=\"580\"\u003e\u003cparam name=\"movie\" value=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/dgU3cNppzO0?version=3\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cparam name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cparam name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cembed src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/dgU3cNppzO0?version=3\" type=\"application\/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"740\" height=\"580\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"\u003e\u003c\/embed\u003e\u003c\/object\u003e",
    "author_name": "LatestNutrition",
    "height": 580,
    "thumbnail_width": 480,
    "width": 740,
    "version": "1.0",
    "author_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/LatestNutrition",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/i1.ytimg.com\/vi\/dgU3cNppzO0\/hqdefault.jpg",
    "type": "video",
    "thumbnail_height": 360
}
```

I've even tried using `width` and `height` parameters in place of / in addition to `maxwidth` and `maxheight`, but I still can't seem to get it larger than 740.

Is there any way to get around this so I can get an embedded video at the dimensions I need them at?

Answer (score 2):

I could'nt paste my code here,

I've used this code for inserting youtube videos in wordpress using custom fields...

I needed to insert videos in a different size from the original. here you need to define your youtube ID and desired Width

I've added some youtube insert options at the end

http://pastebin.com/KRwvSzqP

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a workaround, which isn't as pretty as I'd like it to be, but it works:

```
// Because for some reason Youtube won't allow oEmbed widths greater than 740, so force it to use the proper dimensions
function force_oembed_dimensions($data, $url, $args = array()){
  if (VIDEO_WIDTH > 740)
    $data = preg_replace(array('/ width="\d+"/', '/ height="\d+"/'), array(' width="'.VIDEO_WIDTH.'"', ' height="'.VIDEO_HEIGHT.'"'), $data );
  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'oembed_result', 'force_oembed_dimensions', 10, 3);
```

However, if anyone can suggest a more elegant solution, I'd be more than happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Embedly recently added a way to specify the `width` of the embed. It will take care of the scaling for you. Just add `width=960` to your request.

```
http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?width=960&url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DbDOYN-6gdRE&format=json
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question but thought I'd contribute my findings anyway...

By default, my Youtube files were getting embedded at a 640 width which was bigger than my 615 content width.

I added the following to my functions.php file:

```
// Restrict width of Wordpress auto embed objects
add_filter( 'embed_defaults', 'pstv_new_embed_size' );

function pstv_new_embed_size() {
    $embed_size['width'] = 615; // Enter Max width of your content area
    $embed_size['height'] = 500; // Enter Max height for embedded objects
    return $embed_size; // Return new size 
}
```

At first this still didn't work, until I deactivated the embed feature in the Jetpack plugin. Hope this helps someone else.